# Remove index.php keep parameter only

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this url `http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?page=print-items` and I want to remove `index.php?page=` and only keep what comes after it.

I tried this but it didn't work. it only removes `index.php` and keeps `?page=print-items`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+) index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: The pattern doesn't cover hyphens. And "didn't work" isn't a useful description.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1[L,QSA]` should do the job

Comment: Also are there any conditions that you want to rewrite any specific page or any page you want to redirect to index.php? Kindly do let us know that also.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 No I load components based on this parameter. so I just want to hide everything but the param value

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested as per shown samples.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/?)/?$ index.html?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

OR if you are hitting usre friendly URL and you want to redirect in backend into index.html URL with query string then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !index\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/?)/?$ index.html?page=$1 [NC,L]
```